# Crystal report to pdf's not generating as seen in Preview of Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, pdf-generation

I am generating a crystal report and using a C# prog to break or "burst" the file in to individual pdf's (using this prog.... [Crystal Reports "File Break"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822120/crystal-reports-file-break)   )
When  move the PageHeader section to the "Report Head" section, the details part of crystal reports does not show after the C# prog generates.
When I preview the crystal report from "preview" in crystal reports the detail section is there.....
Any Ideas?
Thanks in advance!!
I would post images but the site will not let me with out more than 10 rep points..
**This is the crystal report preview**

[image]

[image]

And this is after i generated the pdf....  See how the details section is not being populated, even tho in the preview in CR the activities are showing....  This all happened when i switched the top image to be in the group head instead of the page head....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is nothing going on programmatically with hiding/suppressing sections, record selection, etc... generally, if a preview looks different than what is output to PDF or printed, it's always related to printer drivers, fonts chosen, and report printer setup.

For starters, I would make sure you're using a common "HP-compatible" printer as the driver (selected default printer while developing in Crystal) for the report. Also, just for testing purposes, change your report fonts to something VERY simple and "old school" like Courier or Arial. If you get the correct results after this, then go in and tweak/reapply your old fonts.

Also, make sure your individual field objects on the form are set to Can Grow. Additionally, always size your objects bigger than what it looks like it needs. For example, if a field looks like it needs to be 10 characters wide, size it 12 characters wide. This will help with printer and output incompatibilities.