# Easiest way to pass parameters to Crystal Report from C#?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm learning how to pass parameters to a Crystal Report from a C# asp.net webform.  I've found one way to pass parameters, but its 6 lines of code per parameter.  Can anyone suggest a simpler way to pass parameters (both discrete and range) to the report?

Comment: What's the code you're using?

Comment: Standard, such as can be found lots of places online, including http://imar.spaanjaars.com/310/passing-multiple-parameters-to-a-crystal-report-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a question and answer I had that addresses this question:

[Crystal Reports "File Break"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822120/crystal-reports-file-break)

Out of the code that I posted in the answer, here's what I think is relevant to your problem:

```
private readonly CrystalReportViewer reportViewer = new CrystalReportViewer();
...
    crystalReport.Load(this.reportViewer.ReportSource.ToString());

    crystalReport.SetParameterValue("customerId", customerId);
    crystalReport.SetParameterValue("isCurrent", isCurrent);
    crystalReport.SetParameterValue("TotalSales", totalSales);
```

Good luck!

Comment: @Chris B. Behrens: I think you've answered a question which is much more advanced than, and unrelated to, mine.  I just want a good way to pass paramters to a report.  6 lines a piece seems like a nightmere, but I can't think of a way to abstract those lines.

Comment: I've updated the answer to be a little more direct. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your saying that I can load the report, then use the simple method SetParamterValue("", "") to add the parameters quickly?  Do I have to do anything after that, like assign the report back to to the reportviewer's source?

Comment: At that point, you've got an in-memory rendering of the Crystal Report. If you want to write it to disk, you would use the ExportToDisk function. This example exports to PDF: `crystalReport.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, outputPath);`

Comment: I want to then display it in the crystal report viewer on my asp.net webform.

Comment: I haven't done that. I'd give this stuff a try, and maybe look for a Refresh method on the viewer? Something like that.

Comment: Ok, I will.  Do you know what namespace that Report object is in?  I can seem to find it.

Comment: Here are the namespaces I've got in the header:                  using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;                    using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
using CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms;                              I am referencing these two libraries in my proj file:              CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Design
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine          CrystalDecisions.Data.AdoDotNetInterop
CrystalDecisions.Shared
CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms

Comment: Found it, CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.  I wasn't going deep enough.  How can I pass range values using this method?

Comment: I haven't used range parameters, so I'm not sure...maybe break up the range into two discrete parameters?

Comment: Works great for discrete parameters.

Comment: Works great for ranger parameters too, just send 2 discrete parameters and then in the Crystal Report select expert, use both of them (where date is between fromdate and todate).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at http://www.fetal.de/en/crystal-reports-ohne-den-enter-parameter-values-dialog